# Is there a limit to rooting?

Tags: limits, roots

I assume that there will always be limits on mathematical equations, but I never had a thought on it when it comes to square rooting.

I actually mean repetitive square rooting (which might be unnecessary):

$$ \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{... \sqrt{n}}}} $$

Basically, I'm encapsulating an encapsulated square root that's already encapsulating another square root that is also encapsulating a square root that also... (you get the deal).

I'm not sure if there are limits to this, but if possible, how far can I go?

Example of repetitive square rooting:
$$ \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{256}}} = \sqrt{\sqrt{16}} = \sqrt{4} = 2 $$

> It probably could go well with puzzles.

Comment: You are missing understanding of fundamental concepts like functions and real numbers , you be able to answer your own question and ask far better questions if you learn about properties of real numbers and functions , good try though

Comment: Unclear what your second case means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematics allows such repetition as many times as you like;  the concept is not limited by what operations can be practically executed, but limited only but what you can imagine whilst remaining strictly logical.  These concepts can be formalized into a strict definition of what is allowed and what is not, but for day to day purposes, there is no reason why you cannot imagine taking the square root again and again.

In this case the only thing that might stop you repeating a square root would be if at any point you hit a negative number, but that won't happen here (as long as you start with a positive number) because each square root is positive.

In fact you are defining a new operation, or function to use the mathematical term, which you can denote $f(n, x)$.  It is equal to the square root of $x$ repeated $n$ times.  In this construction, $x$ can be any number (whole or a decimal) with $ x \geqslant 0 $ and $n$ any whole number with $n \geqslant 1$.  Or you could extend it to allow the case $n = 0$ as well, by saying $f(0,x)$ is just equal to $x$.

You would write this
$$
f(n, x) = \left\{ \begin{array}
\sqrt {\sqrt {\cdots \sqrt x}}, & \text{square root repeated }n\text{ times,}, n \geqslant 1, x \geqslant 0 \\
x & n=0, x\geqslant 0
\end{array} \right.
$$
and mathematicians would understand exactly what you mean.  You can go on to derive some properties of $f$, for example, when $n \geqslant 1$
$$ f(n,x) = \sqrt{ f(n-1,x)}.$$

Another property, more difficult to prove, is that as $n$ increases $f(n,x)$ gets closer and closer to $1$ provided $x$ is strictly positive, that is $x > 0$.  Mathematically this is written,
$$f(n,x) \to 1 \text{ as }n \to \infty \text{ if } x> 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that

$$\sqrt{\sqrt n}=n^{\frac12\frac12}$$ and after $m$ nestings, $$n^{\frac1{2^m}}, $$ which tends to $$n^0=1$$ by continuity of exponentiation.

---

If you mean nested square roots that result in an integer value, consider

$$\left(n^{2^m}\right)^{\frac1{2^m}}=n.$$

E.g.
$$\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{32768}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}=2.$$

Answer (score -1):

You can square root as much as you want. The only inefficiency is unexpectedly hitting the decimal values.

I can do multiple square roots and get a result of 5:

$$ \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{152,587,890,625}}}} = \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{390,625}}} = \sqrt{\sqrt{625}} = \sqrt{25} = 5 $$

You can try $ \sqrt{\infty} $ but it's probably not helping you.